# java hibernate how update value after record save in certain format

Tags: java, hibernate, insert-update

I want generate unique code in two format for my record  in table.
like following way

1) `"Firstprefix"+"ddmmyyyy"+Sr.number   e.g AD190620151`

2) `"secondprefix"+"ddmmyyyy"+Sr.number  e.g AP190620151`

if another record inserts it will be one of them but serial no change
e.g AD190620152 
    AP190620152
this generated according to another field in record how to do this please  give mi answer.

i have try in following  way

```
     @Override
     public String createOrder(OrderMasterTbl order) {
     getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(order);


     Integer addId=order.getAdType().getId();
     String id = null ;
     if(addId.equals(1))
      {
      id="ap"+new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyy").format(newDate())+order.getId(); 

     }else{
         id="dp"+new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyy").
         format(newDate())+order.getId();
     }

     System.out.print(id);
     order.setOrderCode(id);
     getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(order);

     return id;
}
```

But in this way i am not able to generate proper serial number according two  format .

Comment: Define "I'm not able". What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Hint: read what 'mm' means in SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: sorry  "mm"   means month in two digit form .i.e "MM"

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read the documentation again.

Comment: It should be `SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy")` because `MM` refers to month in date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a proper serial number here because you are using a wrong format for `SimpleDateFormat`, you are referring to month with `m` while it should be `M`, take a look at the **[SimpleDateFormat Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)** for further information.

Your code should be like this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(newDate())
```

**EDIT:**

In order to make the code increment in the last you have just to use two variables `ap` and `dp` in your class that you initialize with `1` and in your method you increment them according to your `if block`, your code  should be like this:

```
 @Override
 public String createOrder(OrderMasterTbl order) {
      getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(order);


      Integer addId=order.getAdType().getId();
      String id = null ;
      if(addId.equals(1)){
          id="ap"+ new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(newDate())+ap;
          ap++;

      }else{
          id="dp"+new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(newDate())+dp;
          dp++;
      }

      System.out.print(id);
      order.setOrderCode(id);
      getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(order);

      return id;
 }
```

Comment: no issue for date format i want change last serial no number instead of  "order.getId()"  i want code  following way -:

Comment: suppose new record inserted if  record is  "AD" type then it code   "AD190620151" , again same type record  inserted then it will code   "AD190620152" please  focus on last digit.but  inserted "AP" type record then  code  "AP190620151" next insert record is "AD " Type then it will be AD190620153 and continue .

Comment: @dipesh take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: OK .but how  maintained this series .suppose  in new transaction another "ap"  type record inserted then  "AP190620152". so how it get serial number code of last type(AP)  and how  it increment .

Comment: In that case you have to manage it in the server side, or maybe in the database.